# How to model and integrate a rails mutliple choice quiz?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, database-design

I am trying to make a little app where users can sign up, login, and be able to view and interact with questions for educational purposes.

I can visualize everything, but I'm having trouble translating that into actual code.

I know that a question model will have

```
Question Title - as a string or text

Question Answer 1 - as a string or text

Question Answer 2 - as a string or text

Question Answer 3 - as a string or text

Question Answer 4 - as a string or text

Question CORRECT ANSWER 5 - as a string or text
```

Naturally, I know the strong_params will have to accept these attributes (parameters?) as well.

How can I make a model where the new-question.html.erb form will pass an array of 5 options, with the ability to mark one as correct? On top of this, I would like to shuffle or randomize the answer choices on each page load.

Any help or guidance would be helpful. Michael Hartl's tutorial is great, but I'm not sure if i'm missing things from it or things aren't clicking.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of answers is always 5 or less, there's nothing wrong using a Question model with 5 text fields for the answers. You can also defaulting the first answer is the correct one and in the view showing the question and answers shuffle the answers.

```
rails g model Question title:text correct_answer:text answer_1:text answer_2:text ...
```

You're just getting started so don't bother too much with separate model for Question, Answer and nested form. Keep it simple.

Comment: What did you mean by the defaulting the first answer? Ideally the user could click a "show answer" button where it could display the right answer, how would that factor in? Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is assume the correct answer is the first one, so you don't need extra field to record which answer is correct. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

sample for database schema

```
  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.references "quiz_id"
    t.string   "question_word"
    t.string   "option1"
    t.string   "option2"
    t.string   "option3"
    t.string   "option4"
    t.integer  "answer",            default: 0
    t.integer  "score",             default: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
  end

  create_table "quizs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "quiz_name"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
  end

  create_table "user_quiz", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.references  "user_id"
    t.references  "quiz_id"
    t.integer  "score",          default: 0
  end
```

sample model relationship, there are 4 models, User, Quiz, Question, UserQuiz

```
  class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :questions
    has_many   :user_quizs
    has_many   :users, :through   => :user_quizs
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :user_quizs
    has_many   :quizs, :through   => :user_quizs
  end

  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :quiz
  end

  class UserQuiz  < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :quiz       
  end
```

for user to choose you can use radio_button_tag, here is [link to learn](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag)